# Flutter how to set mask to text in TextFieldForm programmatically

Tags: flutter

I use library mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.3.0 to set Phone mask in TextFieldFrom.

It stopped working when I set text to TextFieldForm from local files. User phone display without mask.

To set Text is use controller.text = 'text from local files'

How I can handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update mask if you are adding a value to the controller

```
textEditingController.value = maskFormatter.updateMask(mask: "##-##-##-##"); // -> "12-34-56-78"
```